# deleting rows without filtering other values

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
NAME    YEAR      PERCENTAGE
A       2001        NA
A       2002        NA
A       2003        5.0
B       2001        3.3 
B       2002        2.3 
B       2003        NA
```

I want remove rows with NA by selecting the specific rows:

```
NAME    YEAR      PERCENTAGE
A       2003        5.0
B       2001        3.3 
B       2002        2.3
```

and then change B to A,expected output like this:

```
NAME    YEAR      PERCENTAGE
A       2001        3.3 
A       2002        2.3 
A       2003        5.0
```

I tried `subset()`,but since I have other values, it would filter other values which should be remained.

Comment: What about `df[!is.na(df$PERCENTAGE),]` ?

Comment: Do you need to order the output by `YEAR`? You don't mention it, but this is the case in your expected output

Comment: ordering by name and then order the year of each name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the library **dplyr**, you have access to several functions (like *filter()*, *arrange()* or *mutate()*) that able you to modify you dataframe:

```
# the dataframe    
df <- data.frame(
      NAME = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 3),
      YEAR = rep(2001:2003, length = 6),
      PERC = c(NA, NA, 5, 3.3, 2.3, NA)
    )

# load the library
library(dplyr)


df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(PERC)) %>%                         # filter missing values
  arrange(YEAR) %>%                                # order according YEAR
  mutate(NAME = replace(NAME, NAME == 'B', 'A'))   # change values

# result
  NAME YEAR PERC
1    A 2001  3.3
2    A 2002  2.3
3    A 2003  5.0
```

Comment: These are all `dplyr` functions, so just `library(dplyr)` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% na.omit() %>% mutate(NAME = "A")
```

Result:

```
  NAME YEAR PERC
1    A 2003  5.0
2    A 2001  3.3
3    A 2002  2.3
```

Comment: This works for the example data, but it would (a) omit rows that are NA in any column and (b) change any name to "A", not just "B" to "A".

Comment: It is unclear in the question whether those are requirements or not

Comment: Note that I agree with you :) and the other answer is much more general (+1). But I went with the minimal code given the info in the question